# Store link list node address

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

Im currently writing a descending sort function for a doubly link list. I have a flag for the largest value but wondering if there is a way to store the address of a node pointer so i can set its flag outside the loop when operations are done.

Thanks
In this case, our data is relevance

```
float findLargest(DoublyLinkList largestdata)
{
    ListPlayHolder *findbiggest = largestdata.lhead;
    float largest = findbiggest ->relevance;
    while (findbiggest ->next != NULL)
    {
        if (findbiggest ->relevance > largest && findbiggest ->largestFlag != true)
        {
            largest = findbiggest ->relevance;
        }
        findbiggest = findbiggest->next;
    }

    return largest;
}
```

This is no fancy sort, just trying to make a simplistic descending sort of my data. Once i find the largest, i want to set its nodes flag to true. Just need a way to store the address.

Comment: Please show your code. It's really hard to guess your algorithm from a prose description

Comment: Assuming your node is of type `node`, then a pointer to a pointer to a node would be: `node **foo;`

Comment: Instead of `float largest`, store and return `ListPlayHolder* nodeWithLargest`. Begin by replacing `float largest = findbiggest ->relevance;` with `ListPlayHolder* nodeWithLargest = findbiggest;`. The remaining modifications should be obvious and are left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: +1 to Igor. that is the ideal solution, as you exit the loop with `nodeWithLargest` giving you both the largest value *and* the node that brought it to you.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you only need to keep a pointer to the largest element, so nothing fancy, just another `ListPlayHolder*`(which seems like the data type of a pointer to a node - a quite confusing name if you ask me, but whatever).

Also, I would recommend not to initalize `largest` with something pointed to by `findbiggest` - haven't seen your other list code, but I guess that pointer might be `NULL` if the list is empty.

You actually don't need to store the relevance value separately if you instead hold on to a pointer of the currently largest object (thanks @WhozCraig). Here's the modified code:

```
ListPlayHolder* findbiggest = largestdata.lhead;
ListPlayHolder* largest = findbiggest;
while (findbiggest && findbiggest ->next != NULL)
{
    if (findbiggest ->relevance > largest->relevance && findbiggest->largestFlag != true)
    {
        largest = findbiggest;
    }
    findbiggest = findbiggest->next;
}
// here do whatever modifications you need to do to flags? or maybe return largestPtr?
largest->largestFlag = true;
return largest->relevance;
```

Comment: This code assumes the largest element in the list is larger than `(-1.0)`. There is nothing in the OP's question that indicates that as a guarantee or requirement. You would be better served to eliminate the `largest` temporary entirely, and simply use two pointers, one that is walking, and one that maintains a pointer to the current "winner" that is initialized to the list head at startup.

Comment: @WhozCraig sounds like an even better solution. I will modify the code according to your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

If you used `std::list` you could use `std::sort` with different comparison functions and not have to change the node structure for every different ordering sequence.

Another idea is to place your items into a `std::vector` and create `std::list<item *>` for each item.  This would allow you to access the items in the vector in various orders.  For example, one list could be for ascending by title.  Another could be descending by relevance.